# ViewModel not resolved

Tags: reactiveui

I have a UWP Application using ReactiveUI. I navigate to a page with this code:

```
Router.Navigate.Execute(new AccountListViewModel(this));
```

The navigation is done. But the ViewModel I created for the navigation is not assigned to my ViewModel in the View. IViewFor<> is implemented as follows:

```
public sealed partial class AccountListView : IViewFor<AccountListViewModel>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty
        .Register(nameof(ViewModel), typeof(AccountListViewModel), typeof(AccountListView), null);

    public AccountListView()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.WhenActivated(disposables =>
        {
           // My Bindings
           ...
        });
    }

    object IViewFor.ViewModel
    {
        get => ViewModel;
        set => ViewModel = (AccountListViewModel) value;
    }

    public AccountListViewModel ViewModel {
        get => (AccountListViewModel)GetValue(ViewModelProperty);
        set => SetValue(ViewModelProperty, value);
    }
```

Or do I get something completly wrong here?

Comment: Check debug output.maybe something useful is written

Comment: There are some hinting that fields are POCO types. But nothing regarding the ViewModel. Do I look for something specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [ReactiveUI RoutedViewHost implementation for Windows](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/src/ReactiveUI/Platforms/windows-common/RoutedViewHost.cs#L112), which is used for Universal Windows Platform and for Windows Presentation Foundation, the view model should definitely get assigned to the `IViewFor.ViewModel` property. You can track changes in the `IScreen.Router.CurrentViewModel` property to make sure it changes.

If it does, make sure you properly bind your `IScreen.Router` property to the `Router` property of the UWP-specific `RoutedViewHost` XAML control, and routing *should* finally work. In fact, I tested that behavior on UWP recently and it worked fine for me with ReactiveUI 9.13.1 and latest UWP SDK. Try following the [routing tutorial](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/routing/) to fully understand how routing works. If this still won't work for you, then uploading a minimal repro that compiles to GitHub could help us understand your issue better. Also, come join [ReactiveUI Slack](https://reactiveui.net/slack), we are always ready to help out.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the RouteViewHost Class! I haven't realized that it resolves in the WhenActivated and checked before. So it is actually working as expected. And actually I am in the Slack Group. Maybe I should make better use of it :)